# Quasicon... and quasilinearity

Tags: microeconomics, utility

From [the discussion](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/52390/please-check-those-two-production-functions-they-also-seems-to-be-quasiconvex/52392?noredirect=1#comment85225_52392) under [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/52390/please-check-those-two-production-functions-they-also-seems-to-be-quasiconvex/52392):

Can utility function $U(x,y)$ that is both quasiconcave and quasiconvex always be transformed (via some positive monotonic function) into a quasilinear form $v(x) + y$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not the case. Consider $u(x, y) = \lfloor x + y \rfloor$ i.e. greatest integer less than or equal to $x+y$. It is both quasi-concave and quasi-convex, but no transformation of the kind $v(x) + y$ exist. This is because $v(x) + y$ is strictly increasing in $y$, but $u$ is not.

Another much simpler example is $u(x, y) = 0$.

Comment: I have question on game theory.  I will be appreciate if you help me by sharing your suggestions and hints. Thank you https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/52468/principal-agent-problem